# jHipster: How to add table, fields to table on the production?

Tags: java, jhipster

How to add table, fields to table to the production in jHipster project? 
I read this https://www.jhipster.tech/development/, but it for development.
Would product database has updated after this:

```
./mvnw  -DskipTests  -Pprod package
```

or after start :

```
./my-project.war
```

The part of my pom.html :

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
            <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase_dev</url>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Does it mean i should change  for select a database which i want to update?

What is the sequence of actions when adding fields in product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Jhipster comes with liquibase product for that.

Comment: You have to deploy the new version of the application. At startup Liquidbase will check the database version with the application version and apply the needed updates.

Answer (score 1):

Jhipster has sub-generator that does this to you.

It can be invoked by running

> jhipster entity  --[options]

Reference for those options can be found by typing

> jhipster entity --help

If you need you can find more information in here: [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/)